# Virtual columns mysql

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to add a virtual column in this SELECT statement with a count() of the products for each phone?

I want to dynamically create a new column named count which will be the number of products for a phone. e.g. 10 products for an iphone 5s.

```
    $query"SELECT *, count(products.phone_id) as count..."
```

My query is:

```
    $query="SELECT * FROM phones INNER JOIN products on phones.id=products.phone_id";
    $query .= " WHERE phones.name LIKE '%". $searchInput . "%'";
    $query .= " AND phones.id IN (SELECT phone_id FROM products WHERE phone_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY phone_id)";
    $query .= " GROUP BY phones.id";
```

Comment: Yes you can, did you try it?  Don't think you need that `subquery` either since you are using a `join`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 $query="SELECT *,count(phones.id) as count FROM phones INNER JOIN products on phones.id=products.phone_id";
    $query .= " WHERE phones.name LIKE '%". $searchInput . "%'";
    $query .= " AND phones.id IN (SELECT phone_id FROM products WHERE phone_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY phone_id)";
    $query .= " GROUP BY phones.id";
```